# Read CSV with d3 (v3 or v4), save data and callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3js v4 to bring and read a csv file. I am not using any frameworks. Simply using it like it shows here: https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#csv

I notice that in all examples they just send it to console. log and I really need to keep the data stored in the object.

If I do console.log() in the callback it prints them, so I know it is reading the file and bringing the data, but even if I create a variable inside, or I use a variable brought from 'this', or copy the values into an object, it all fails. This is not because of the asynchronicity because the file is read and it works, then it goes out of scope. I need it to be saved out of the scope of the d3.csv.

A simple version of the code with two options to try and copy the parsed CSV object.

```
containerobject = {
    readCSV: function (astring, thecsv) {
        console.log(astring); 
        console.log(thecsv);
        var answer; //I want to store the parsed csv here
        var request = d3.csv(
            thecsv,
            function (d) {
                return {
                    name: d.name,
                    x: Number(d.x),
                    y: Number(d.y)
                };
            },
            function (rows) {
                if (rows === undefined || rows === null) {
                    alert('error');
                }
                if (astring == "one") {
                    answer = d3.nest()
                        .key(function (d) { return d.letters; })
                        .entries(rows); //console.log(answer); This prints
                } else if (astring == "two") {
                    answer = Object.assign({},(function(){ return d3.nest()
                        .key(function (d) { return d.letters; })
                        .entries(rows);}())); //console.log(answer); This prints
                }
            }
        );
        console.log("answer", answer); // this is undefined
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Note: As sometimes it happens, it was all working recently and now it just doesn't.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is 
`var request = d3.csv(...)` is an ajax call.
So return answer will not have any value when `readCSV` is called.

I would suggest you to use **promise**:

```
containerobject = {
    readCSV: function (astring, thecsv) {
        console.log(astring); 
        console.log(thecsv);
        var answer; //I want to store the parsed csv here
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var request = d3.csv(
            thecsv,
            function (d) {
                return {
                    name: d.name,
                    x: Number(d.x),
                    y: Number(d.y)
                };
            },
            function (rows) {
                if (rows === undefined || rows === null) {
                    promise.reject('error');
                }
                if (astring == "one") {
                    promise.resolve(d3.nest()
                        .key(function (d) { return d.letters; })
                        .entries(rows));
                } else if (astring == "two") {
                    promise.resolve(Object.assign({},(function(){ return d3.nest()
                        .key(function (d) { return d.letters; })
                        .entries(rows);}())))
                }
            }
        );

        })

        return promise;
    }
}
```

**Change 2**

Now at the place when you call read CSV add then callback to get the object returned from ajax.

```
containerObject.readCSV().then(function(data) {
 //do your stuff with csv parsed data.
})
```

A working example for [promise](https://plnkr.co/edit/uot7rDCkO0tZBL8jHH3u?p=preview)

Comment: @altocumulus is there already a v5? They change the API too much between versions it is going to be hard to maintain code like this. I am looking and I don't see any v5, latest is (4.13.0) according to the website

Comment: @altocumulus and can you tell me how to handle promises using v5?

Comment: @Using v5 it tells me now that there is authorization required, but the file is completely open to the public, I don't know if I have to set any CORS permissions somewhere even if the file is in the same server and all.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks for the pointers. Currently i solved it using promise. Hope this should nail it in v4.